# Is there a non-allocating way to modify elements of single-reference packed arrays?

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra, packed-arrays

I need to repeatedly increment cuboidal chunks of a 3D image. The image is large - on the order of 1G elements.

The only way I know of doing it using built-in Image functions is:

```
accumulator = accumulator ~ ImageAdd ~ ImagePad[ImageConstant[1,size], padding]`
```

This of course constantly allocates the constant images and the padded outputs. Tens of thousands them, and at these sizes, it's slow.

So, instead, I can use a packed array to represent the image data, and add to that using `Part` and `AddTo`:

```
regions = { Splice[{1;;2, 3;;4, 5;;6}, Part], ... };
size = {1100, 1100, 1100};

accumulator = ConstantArray[0, size];
Assert[Developer`PackedArrayQ[accumulator]];

(* accumulator has a single reference here *)
Map[{region} |-> accumulator[[region]] += 1, regions];

result = Image3D[accumulator, "Bit16"];
```

Unfortunately, the `AddTo` function doesn't seem to have a specialization that would not reallocate, in spite of the modified array having just one reference*. Judging by the system memory use, each `AddTo` clones the image, modifies it, sets `accumulator` to it, then deallocates `accumulator`.

Is there some incantation that would do it without allocating memory?

* Bonus Question: Is there any way to inspect an object refcount in Mathematica?

---

The exact code I'm using is in a Module, and is:

```
gridCuboidImageData = {gcuboids} |->
   Module[{gridSize, i, gcuboid, start, size, ex, ey, ez, 
     n = Length[gcuboids], imageData},
    gridSize = Plus @@ gcuboids[[1]];
    (* if compiled to C, replace with: imageData=PadLeft[{{{}}},
    Reverse@gridSize] *)
    imageData = ConstantArray[0, Reverse@gridSize];
    Assert[Developer`PackedArrayQ[imageData]];
    For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
     gcuboid = gcuboids[[i]];
     size = gcuboid[[3]];
     start = gcuboid[[1]];
     start = {start[[1]], gridSize[[2]] - start[[2]] - size[[2]], 
       gridSize[[3]] - start[[3]] - size[[3]]};
     ex = start[[1]] + size[[1]];
     ey = start[[2]] + size[[2]];
     ez = start[[3]] + size[[3]];
     imageData[[1 + start[[3]] ;; ez, 1 + start[[2]] ;; ey, 
       1 + start[[1]] ;; ex]] += 1;
     ];
    imageData
    ];
```

Comment: What exactly is in the list `regions`?

Comment: Has `Do[accumulator[[region]] + 1, {region, regions}]` the same problems?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I updated the question. `regions` is a list of lists of `Span`-s that get spliced into the `Part[accumulator, <here>]`. I haven't tried the `Do` form, but somehow doubt it will be different. The `Map` is not really changing anything. It is the `accumulator[[a;;b, c;;d, e;;f]] += 1` expression that isn't doing what I'd expect it to.

Answer (score 5):

After I wrote the *C* code below, it came to my mind that the first thing you should do in your *Mathematica* session is to set

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
```

Otherwise, at least on my machine, repeated calls of something  even so innocent as `accumulator = ConstantArray[0, {1100,1100,1100}];` will quickly fill all RAM and lead to memory compression or swapping.

---

Sometimes, when one needs particular control of memory, it may be better to write plain *C* code and use *LibraryLink* to compile and link it to the *Mathematica* session. Even if the same can be done with pure *Mathematica* code, this way you don't have to bother how *Mathematica* handles the memory and you are guaranteed to get nearly optimal performance (on the CPU).

Here a simple example that takes the 3-tensor as `"Shared"` array and modifies it in-place.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
Quiet[LibraryFunctionUnload[incCuboid]];
ClearAll[incCuboid];
incCuboid = Module[{lib, code, name},

    name = "incCuboid";
    
    code=StringJoin[
"
#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int "<>name<>"(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
{
    MTensor acc_    = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    MTensor ranges_ = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[1]);

          mint * const acc    = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(acc_);
    const mint * const ranges = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(ranges_);
    const mint * const d      = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(acc_);

    const mint n = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(ranges_)[0];

    for( mint l = 0; l < n; ++l )
    {
        const mint r [3][2] = {
            { ranges[6 * l + 0]-1, ranges[6 * l + 1] },
            { ranges[6 * l + 2]-1, ranges[6 * l + 3] },
            { ranges[6 * l + 4]-1, ranges[6 * l + 5] }
        };

        for( mint i = r[0][0]; i < r[0][1]; ++i )
        {
            for( mint j = r[1][0]; j < r[1][1]; ++j )
            {
                for( mint k = r[2][0]; k < r[2][1]; ++k )
                {
                    ++acc[ (i * d[1] + j ) * d[2] + k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    libData->MTensor_disown(acc_);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}"];

    lib=CreateLibrary[code, name, "Language"->"C++"];

    LibraryFunctionLoad[ lib, name,{{Integer,3,"Shared"},{Integer,3,"Constant"}},"Void"]
];
```

Here a simple usage example:

Initialization:

```
size = {1100, 1100, 1100};
accumulator = ConstantArray[0, size];
```

Running the actual incrementation:

```
regions = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 6}}};
incCuboid[accumulator, regions];
```

Here is a timing and correctness test:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
size = {1100, 1100, 1100};
a = ConstantArray[0, size];
b = ConstantArray[0, size];

n = 10000;
maxdist = 10;

regions = With[{r1 = RandomInteger[{1, 1100 - maxdist}, {n, 3}]},
   Transpose[{r1, r1 + RandomInteger[{1, maxdist}, {n, 3}]}, {3, 1, 2}]
   ];

Do[
  ++a[[r[[1, 1]] ;; r[[1, 2]], r[[2, 1]] ;; r[[2, 2]], r[[3, 1]] ;; r[[3, 2]]]]
  , {r, regions}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
incCuboid[b, regions]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.14132
>
> 0.090627
>
> True

Apparently, the speed difference is not that big. And with `$HistoryLength = 0` I also don't see any memory leaks. If you write large blocks, then both methods will be roughly at the same speed. The only difference is the uncompiled `Do` loop after all; the blockwise incrementation code for `++a[[r[[1, 1]] ;; r[[1, 2]], r[[2, 1]] ;; r[[2, 2]], r[[3, 1]] ;; r[[3, 2]]]]` should already be done in a compiled library with the nested loop like my `i`-`j`-`k` loop. But for small block sizes, `incCuboid` for to be faster. For example, it is 20 times faster then `Do` if `maxdist = 4`.

**Potential improvements**

If the blocks are many and very small (and thus fit into L1-cache), then you might get a 20 % improvement if `regions` is lexicographically sorted. The reason is cache locality. However, sorting `regions` with `Sort` will take longer than what you will save. But maybe you can generate `regions` in a sorted manner?

If the each region is sufficiently large, then it might be worthwhile to parallelize the loop over `i`. Or if you know that your regions are disjoint, then the loop over `l` can be parallelized easily, instead.

Comment: I did just that but with more error checking :) I used the [LibraryLink Utilities](https://wolframresearch.github.io/LibraryLinkUtilities/) C++ framework to write similar functions, including ImageAddTo that works just like ImageAdd except adds to a shared image. I don't think the history length really makes a difference for me: all of this is done inside of a module, so no history is kept except for the final sum. Thank you for your answer - it confirms that writing a LibrayLink paclet for that is really the only sure-fire way to go.

Comment: You're welcome! And, yupp, over the years I also moved more away from looking for _Mathematica_-only solution to more gritty low-level coding. Nonetheless, I love _Mathematica_ for quick prototyping and visualization.

Comment: Thank you also for the pointer to LLU. Indeed, I have worked only with the _C_-interface so far and found it extremely wordy. The biggest annoyances are `MArgument_getXXX`, `MArgument_setXXX`, and `libData->MTensor_getXXXData` Thus, I wrote a header file with a couple of C++ wrappers and that declares a global instance `WolframLibraryData libData;` I have not understood till today, way this struct is passed around that much.

Comment: Then I can define a template `template<typename T> inline T & get( MArgument marg );` and can specialize it like `template<> inline mcomplex & get<mcomplex>( MArgument marg ) { return *((marg).cmplex); }`, etc.

Comment: LLU provides a wrapper macro that takes the name of a function. It’s used like `LLU_FUNCTION(MyFun) { }`. The code block can throw exceptions, all error handling on the LibraryLink/Wolfram Library side is done with exceptions, so no need to check error codes. Access to parameters and return values is done using the `mngr` variable - an instance of a manager class that handles the interface.

Comment: With LLU, a function that takes an integer and returns it looks as follows: `LLU_FUNCTION(IntIdentity) { int i = mngr.get(0); mngr.put(i); }`. There are type-safe wrappers for containers so that the compiler can pre-generate code for any contained type, eg. an image of bytes, words, ints, reals,… The wrapper sets up an instance of `mngr` to use. Convenient type conversions either exist or can be added. Eg. strings are compatible with `std::string` and `char*`.

Comment: Returning a string IIRC: `LLU_FUNCTION(GetHello) { std::string name = mngr.get(0); mngr.put(“Hello, “+name); }`